# Google consent screen not showing up while integrating Google Drive

Tags: c#, google-oauth

I am having trouble integrating Google Drive in my ASP.NET web application. It is not showing up the consent screen where user can enter his/her Google credentials to authorize my application.

Below is my code:

```
String CLIENT_ID = "XXXXXX";
String CLIENT_SECRET = "XXXXXX";
String APP_USER_AGENT = "<Application - Name>";
string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
DriveService service=null;

try
{
    var dbDataStore = new DatabaseDataStore("<DBServer>", "<DBUser>", "<Pwd>", "<DataBase>");
    UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = CLIENT_ID, ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET },
            scopes, Convert.ToString(Session["UserId"]), CancellationToken.None, dbDataStore).Result;

    service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = APP_USER_AGENT,
    });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Comment: did you ever get this to work? would be nice to know the solution

Answer (score 0):

My understanding for every google api calls we should get permission

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#consentpageexperience

You could use https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?chromeless=1#OGX:ManageOauthClients for overriding the permission